# implement financial microservice using node.js | python | R

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, microservices, financial

I'm developing a tourist web app with node.js and microservics.

I need to develop a `pricing` service which will do all the calculation for the guest (price for night, taxes, VAT, discounts etc).

Moreover, I need those calculation will be easy to dynamically change and control.

**From my past experience, doing those calcs in common web programming languages and/or storing math formulas in the db end with a mess**.

Are there any alternative solutions for this? From what I read so far language like `python`, `R` or `Java` can fit to the job. However, is there any specific library within those which aimed for pricing?

Comment: which database you use , can you add that?

Comment: Postgres, mongodb

Answer (score 0):

On can do calulations in (datamodel / class) in javascript

1 : you can create a javascript class

```
   function sales(){
    let self = this
    this.address = '';
    this.personname = '';
    this.totalVat = 0
    this.items = [];
    this.calculateTax = function(){
       let tax = ...compute items array and set 
       self.totalVat = tax
     }   
   }
```

### Note :

**you can use this data model if you are going to use it only on ui**

else if

**you want to use it on server then you can use same datamodel on server**

esle if

**you want to use on both server and ui then**

(you can maintain only 1 copy of this model shared by server and ui , here you can use require.js bundling to take help of sharing one datamodel , also there are nice articles that show how to share js datamodels)

**in Case Of (you want to use on both server and ui then)**

You mentioned database , you create mechanism to store formula in database and you can generate sales_datamodel.js on server whenever any changes are done in datamodel in db

Comment: reply when stuck

Comment: I'm looking for more complete solution like using framework or dedicated programming language like R for example.

Comment: you questionnaire information is very limited , i answered according to that question..can you be more specific with question and update question , Like you said You want to use R language - mention this in question ,also mention what you were trying earlier with some sudo code snippet

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

@wizard I would share here something .

If you have complex calculation or any type of calculation do it in db end if feasible.

The best approach
`postgres`

to do this type of process is to make function (PL\SQL) block . If you are using postgres create all calculation in postgres .

This is why node.js was design , no calculation in node.js end .

`mongodb`

if you are working with mongodb with this approach then i will recommend you to go with

`Stored JavaScript in MongoDB`